# 2D Infrared spectroscopy for bulk systems using molecular dynamics

Tags: molecular-dynamics, spectroscopy, vibrations, phonon-density-of-state, correlation-functions

There are some questions and answers ([1](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1550/what-are-some-methods-for-modeling-bulk-phase-infrared-spectra),[2](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/2283/how-exactly-does-one-compute-the-vibrational-density-of-states-from-the-output-o)) on this site regarding simple infrared and vibrational density of states calculations with molecular dynamics and there any simple algorithmic descriptions of these quantities using velocity-velocity correlation functions. But there are not many clear descriptions/resources available for 2D infrared spectroscopy though there are some articles available describing such calculations:

1. T. l. C. Jansen, B. M. Auer, Mino Yang, J. L. Skinner; Two-dimensional infrared spectroscopy and ultrafast anisotropy decay of water. *J. Chem. Phys.* **2010**; 132 (22): 224503. https://doi.org/10.1063/1.3454733
2. T. l. C. Jansen,J. Knoester; Nonadiabatic Effects in the Two-Dimensional Infrared Spectra of Peptides:  Application to Alanine Dipeptide. *J. Phys. Chem. B* **2006** 110 (45), 22910-22916. https://doi.org/10.1021/jp064795t

Can some who has experience implementing or calculating such data elaborate step-by-step on how to calculate a 2D infrared spectra or a related quantity?